# How can i use a variable inside sed cmd when Variable again has special character?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, sh

**# test-1, this is okay, which deletes the given line in given 'cshrc' file**

```
sed -i '\:alias reml rm -rf ${ENIP_HOME}/log/*:d' cshrc
```

**# test-2, This does not delete the line in given 'cshrc' file**

```
LINE="alias reml rm -rf ${ENIP_HOME}/log/*"
sed -i '\:$LINE:d' cshrc
```

Above sed cmd does not remove the line from 'cshrc; file, How i can perform line deletion in test-2 ?

Comment: it is anyway not safe. `/.../` is regex. if your line has `.*`, you command will surprise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) when it comes to variable expansion. In your setting it suffices to just replace the double quotes by single quotes in the `LINE=` definition, so that `${ENIP_HOME}` is carried over without being replaced (by the empty string, if the variable is not defined).

You also need to use double quotes in the `sed` line, so that `$LINE` is replaced by the definition of the variable.

Comment: Using  `(')` in  `LINE=` and  `(")` in the sed solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: Great, feel free to accept my answer then (there should be a green check mark next to the vote arrows).